# 360 Video Annotation

Tags: dictionary, video, annotations, 360-degrees

This is more of a general question as I am not sure if this is possible within swift 3.0 but within my app, instead of an image next to my annotation title, I would like a 360 video. This would allow the user to have a more interactive and interesting view of the location provided. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I saw on GitHub some libraries can do this, I didn't try with video, you can check out, it's based on Apple's 3D drawing Framework  Metal and SceneKit.

https://github.com/ejeinc/MetalScope